# How to remove duplicate records based on pair of values in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have written a PowerShell script in which I am reading file (not necessary that it will is CSV). In this I have two columns, case number and cin number. I want to remove all records if this pair is getting repeated

Input File:

```
 abc  1234    class1
 def  1234    class2
 abc  5678    class3
 def  1234    class4
 ghi  1001    class5
```

Desired Output is:

```
 abc  1234    class1
 def  1234    class2
 abc  5678    class3
 ghi  1001    class5
```

For this I have wrriten following script (input file will have more columns):

```
$inputFile ="D:\powershell\test files\01PRD_MAGI_12_03.txt";
$outputFile = "D:\powershell\test files\output.txt" ;
$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter]"$outputFile"


$seenPair = @{}

$lines = Get-Content $inputFile
$count = 0

foreach($line in $lines){
    $count = $count + 1

    #write all header rows and last line as it is in output file
    if($count -eq 1  -or  $count -eq 2  -or  $count -eq 3 -or $line.startsWith('*') -or $line.startsWith('-')){
        $stream.WriteLine($line);
    } 
    else{
        $ldrCaseNum = $line.Substring(3,7)
        $cin = $line.Substring(70,9)

        if($seenPair.Contains($ldrCaseNum)){
            $cinVal = $seenPair.Get_Item($ldrCaseNum)
            if($cin -eq $cinVal){
                continue;
            }
            else{
                $stream.WriteLine($line)
            }
        }
        else{
            $seenPair.Add($ldrCaseNum,$cin)
            $stream.WriteLine($line)
        }

    }
}

$stream.close()
```

But in this case, If a same pair is getting repeated which is stored in $seenPair variable then that record will get removed. But for same key, different value pair will get repeated then it won't remove it, because it holds already a value for that key.

Example:

```
 abc  1234    class1
 def  1234    class2
 abc  5678    class3
 abc  5678    class3
 def  1234    class4
 ghi  1001    class5
```

output will be:

```
 abc  1234    class1
 def  1234    class2
 abc  5678    class3
 abc  5678    class3
 ghi  1001    class5
```

Desired output is:

```
 abc  1234    class1
 def  1234    class2
 abc  5678    class3
 ghi  1001    class5
```

Is there any other solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to leave parsing the file into objects as an exercise for the reader, and focus on removing duplicate pairs.

```
# First we have an array of objects
$Objects = @'
abc 1234 class1
def 1234 class2
abc 5678 class3
def 1234 class4
ghi 1001 class5
'@ |ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter " " -Header Case,Cin,Class
```

Now, all we need in order to remove objects where the "Case/Cin" combination already exists is `Sort-Object -Unique`:

```
PS C:\> $Objects |Sort-Object -Property Case,Cin -Unique
case cin  class
---- ---  -----
abc  1234 class1
abc  5678 class3
def  1234 class4
ghi  1001 class5
```

Comment: when I run your 2nd command, the data is coming as header = "",header = "",.... inside csv on each row. Why is it like that?

Comment: inside which csv? I'm not outputting to csv

Comment: I read the content of $Objects |Sort-Object -Property Case,Cin -Unique this commant in a $data variable and I am writing it into a file..